# Kubernetes Dashboard Results in Resource Not Found

Tags: kubernetes

I'm having some problems with the Kubernetes Dashboard not showing any information when I tried to access it:

[image]

I checked the version that I'm using:

```
$ kubectl version --short
Flag --short has been deprecated, and will be removed in the future. The --short output will become the default.
Client Version: v1.26.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.26.0+k3s1
```

Both the client and the server versions are indeed the same, so I'm not sure what is causing the Dashboard UI to not show any information? Any ideas?

EDIT: I even lowered the version of my kubectl and my k3s server, but still I do not see the Unknown error go away.

```
Client Version: v1.25.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.25.6+k3s1

$ kubectl get clusterrolebinding admin-user
NAME         ROLE                        AGE
admin-user   ClusterRole/cluster-admin   19h

$ kubectl get sa -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   SECRETS   AGE
default                0         19h
kubernetes-dashboard   0         19h
admin-user             0         19h
```

Comment: Can you describe how did you set up your dashboard?If possible can you attach your yaml files?

Comment: Just followed this documentation here: https://docs.k3s.io/installation/kube-dashboard

Comment: Check your **serviceAccount** and **ClusteroleBinding** is created properly and in right namespace.If possible try to lower your server version to 1.25 because in the [official kubernetes-dashboard](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases) page they mention the latest dashboard will support upto server v1.25. I followed the same documentation, it works for me but my setup details are like this 
Client Version: v1.26.0
Kustomize Version: v4.5.7
Server Version: v1.24.8. Hope you find this info useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might happen for various reasons like Either **ClusterRoleBinding** or **ServiceAccount** is not created properly. Sometimes it will be related to Compatibility as well. Try these troubleshooting steps

1. In case if you are creating a **Service Account** and **ClusterRoleBinding** manually then make sure you are creating in proper namespace and giving proper configurations and roles.

you can use these commands to get the detials about SA and rolebindings

```
$kubectl get sa -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                   SECRETS   AGE
admin-user             0         61m
    
$kubectl get clusterrolebinding admin-user
NAME         ROLE                        AGE
admin-user   ClusterRole/cluster-admin   62m
```

2. Check whether the `dashboard` version is compatible with the
   `server` version. You can find the compatibility information in
   [official kubernetes-dashboard
   page](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/releases) on github.
   If your server is not compatible then try lowering the version.(In your case try lowering the version to 1.25).
3. Check this [official documentation](https://github.com/AcalephStorage/kubernetes-dashboard#documentation) for detailed
   kubernetes-dashboard troubleshoot

These SO links have similar issues [SO1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68885798/kubernetes-dashboard-web-ui-has-nothing-to-display) [SO2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59141055/kubernetes-dashboard-unknown-server-error-after-login)